# Values not showing in Firebase react and material-ui

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I have a problem where I can dispatch and push the things to firebase but there is no data  in the firebase, the strings are empty. I am wondering if the material-ui is causing the issue here or am I missing something? And here is also the code. I have been trying to figure out why the values are not showing and been wondering there is a mistake somewhere in the code because I believe that it should work technically and

[empty values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8lTI.png)

// Action

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { 
    CREATE_USER,
    UPDATE_FORM
} from './ActionTypes';

export const formUpdate = ({ prop, value }) => {
    console.log("LOG", prop, value)
    return {
        type: UPDATE_FORM,
        payload: { prop, value }
    }
}

export const createProfile = ({ firstName, lastName, email, company, billingMethod }) => {
    // const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.database().ref(`/profile`)
            .push({ firstName, lastName, email, company, billingMethod })
            .then(() => {
                dispatch({ type: CREATE_USER })
            })
            .then(() => {
                toast.info("User profile was created !", {
                    position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
                    autoClose: 1000
                  });
            })
    }
}
```

// Reducer

```js
import {
    CREATE_USER,
    UPDATE_FORM
} from '../Actions/ActionTypes';


const INITIAL_STATE = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    company: '',
    billingMethod: '',
}

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action: any) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_FORM:
            return { ...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value }
        case CREATE_USER:
            return INITIAL_STATE
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: and the file //File

https://pastebin.com/04Z5heeL

Comment: "I have a problem where I can dispatch and push the things to firebase but there is no data." Please clarify, where is there no data?  What are you expecting to happen and what is happening now?

Comment: @JoshPittman I edited the question. Basically when the thing pushes this is what I see https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8lTI.png Those fields should have data in there

Comment: You have no problem at using firebase functions. You are not getting the data from your form. Console.log your data first to see if you are getting the data.

Comment: @JukkaKoivu try to add more code. Connected component to redux which is dispatching create/update action.

Comment: @octobus I have made something similar before and that is working but this one doesn't work because for the some reason the data from the form isn't going forward. I have console logged it and it says null expect for the billingMethod but that one either doesn't go to firebase db.

Comment: @lavor I have both update and the create functions in the above that are handling it and also the reducer. Dispatch is working because something is going to firebase just the data from the form isn't passing through for some reason that I don't understand

Comment: Where do you call `createProfile ({ firstName, lastName, email, company, billingMethod })`. If the `firstName, lastName, email, company` and coming up as null then it means there is a problem in the actual component where this function is being called.

Comment: You probably made a type mistake somewhere can you show the code that how you pass the data to there. Your firebase functions work but you are not passing the correct data @JukkaKoivu

Comment: @octobus Here: https://pastebin.com/TepX1Tgv

Comment: @JoshPittman could it be the case that they are not in the same component because of the material-ui?

Answer (score 0):

In pastebin.com/TepX1Tgv , when you define `const getStepContent = (step, props) => {...}` it takes two parameters.

When you implement it you only pass one parameter

`<Typography className={classes.instructions}>{getStepContent(activeStep)}</Typography>`

Pass the props parameter so that all your components can receive their props.

Comment: not sure if I understood that one. So in the ```getStepContent(activeStep, props)``` ?

Comment: Yes, all of your components are based on props coming from this function and yet you don't pass in the props `<Typography className={classes.instructions}>{getStepContent(activeStep, ???NO PROPS HERE???)}</Typography>`

Comment: I added the props there but my form fields goes straigh empty when trying to type on the input field and same happens that values are empty

Comment: The props are empty going into `getStepContent` ? Can you please log your props at each step and identify where they are getting lost.

Comment: For example the first name in console log provides this https://i.imgur.com/4fJAEr0.png but the billing method gives this https://i.imgur.com/St5zhye.png but when I type in the name it disappears and the data won't go to firebase

Comment: You seem to be passing in the entire event, not the values you need. Instead of passing in the event from the input pass in `event.target.value`

Comment: Now I get this ```LOG firstName undefined``` code currently is https://pastebin.com/2MFNDHrW